# How to preserve white space when reading fixed length text file

Tags: coldfusion, whitespace, readfile

I am reading a .txt file that is, in essence, a csv type file with rows and columns, only the columns are separated by literal [space] characters. Each column has a predefined length of these characters, as given in a data definition file.

[image: Sample of Text File]

Below is what I have tried, but it ignores white space. The numbers are what's given me to differentiate columns.

```
function formatTextFile(input){
    var readFile = fileOpen(input,"read");
    var line1 = FileReadLine(readFile);
    var line2 = FileReadLine(readFile);
    line2 = REReplace(line2,"[^(.{7}.{10}.{47}.{34}.{14}.{13}.{15}.{22}.{28}.{18}.{2})]+[ ]", "|", "all");
    return line2;
}
```

This is the output from that:

```
|1. 16-1268|5/2/201|31530|$0.00|404|AP
```

I thought about trying to use java to do string formatting. I haven't figured this one out.

Comment: Why do you think ColdFusion ignores whitespace when it reads a file?

Comment: I modified the question and title to better describe the issue. The regex is probably what is modifying white space. Regex's are not my forte, but you might try backreferences: `REReplace(text,"^(.{7})..etc...(.{2})\s+$", "\1|..etc..|\11");`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you ultimately doing with the results?

Comment: @danbracuk when i did a readline of the file, the variable it returned had reduced the line to all single spaces between 'columns'. The spaces are definitely there in the original file, I'm just not aware of how coldfusion handles them.

Comment: @Leigh putting it in a query object

Comment: *RE: when i did a readline of the file* It is not the readLine removing all of the spaces. It is the regex (dump `line2` before the replace). You need a different expression. Like I mentioned above, you could use backreferences, but ... personally I prefer string functions as mentioned in the answer below.  *RE: putting it in a query object* For display (not insertion into a db), right?

Comment: @Leigh yes string functions is the way to go. However I did a writeDump of the read line before I did any regex and still was left with no spaces. Does writeDump exclude the extra whitespace?

Comment: @MattWilde - By default it generates html, which collapses white space. Either use `format="text"` or an old school `writeOutput` and `<pre>` tags. Both displayed the original white space for me.

Comment: (Edit) Ugh... brain glitch. I meant to type *subexpressions*, not backreferences.  BTW, if the results are being inserted into a db (rather than displayed on screen) there are better options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why even bother with regex if you have fixed column widths? Consider the following:

```
<cfscript>

    line = "ab  12  xy 654   +1234    ";
    columnLengths = [4, 4, 3, 6, 1, 8];

    o = readFixedLine(line, columnLengths);

    function readFixedLine(line, columnLengths) {

        var cells = [];
        var offset = 1;

        for (length in columnLengths) {
            cells.add( mid(line, offset, length) );
            offset += length;
        }

        return cells;
    }

    // cells read (the dump doesn't display whitespaces)
    writeDump(o);
    /*
        whitespaces represented as asterisks
        [1] ab**
        [2] 12**
        [3] xy*
        [4] 654***
        [5] +
        [6] 1234****
    */

    // proving that whitespaces are kept
    for (entry in o) {
        writeOutput( len(entry) & "<br>" );
    }
    /*
        4
        4
        3
        6
        1
        8
    */

</cfscript>
```

The `mid` function is failsafe (in that regard), so you don't even have to worry about empty lines or missing columns. However, `fileReadLine` trims trailing whitespaces, so you are out of luck here. Only Java can help at this point (read your file with `Stream` or `BufferedReader`).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Alex for providing a great solution. Java is the way to go and his method is very functional. I simply want to show how I implemented it into constructing a query.

Left with an array of columns and rows which you can put into a query object with `QueryAddColumn`. I had to mess with the column lengths but the java method is the way to go.Thanks again @Alex.

```
function formatTextFile(input){
        var fileReader = createObject("java","java.io.FileReader").init(input);
        var bufferedReader = createObject("java","java.io.BufferedReader").init(fileReader);
        var lineReader = createObject("java","java.io.LineNumberReader").init(bufferedReader);

        var columnLengths = [7,10,47,34,14,13,16,22,75,18,2];
        var rows = ArrayNew(2);
        var line = lineReader.readLine();
        //skip empty lines
        while(!structKeyExists(Local,"line")&&!len(trim(Local.line))){
            line = lineReader.readLine();
        }

        while(isDefined("line")){
            var cells = ArrayNew(1);
            var offset = 1;
            for(var i = 1; i<=ArrayLen(columnLengths); i++){
                cells.add(mid(line,offset,columnLengths[i]));
                offset+=columnLengths[i];
                ArrayAppend(rows[i],cells[i]);
            }
            line = lineReader.readLine();
        }
        return rows;        
    }
```

[image: Image of the output]

Comment: (Edit) Nice work. Though if you are running CF9+, better to use the `Local` scope and `structKeyExists(Local, "line")` instead of `IsDefined("line")`. Otherwise, there is the potential for unexpected results if that same variable name exists in some other scope (variables, url, form, etcetera). Also, not sure that first `while` loop is really needed.

Comment: @Leigh Good point with the scope. We are using Framework/1 on our server which may not make a difference but I am not used to using those scopes in the controllers. Probably best practice. I figured the first while loop would skip over empty lines. but instead I should probably do a `if(!len(line)){}` check?

Comment: Yes, it does not skip empty lines. It returns whatever is there (may be an empty string) OR `null` when it reaches the EOF. To find the first non-empty line, ensure it exists, then check the length: `structKeyExists(Local, "line") && !len(Local.line)`. Might also throw a `trim()` in there if you want to ignore all white space lines.

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for comments)

Side note about the original question, the white space is being removed by the regular expression, not [FileReadLine](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/filereadline.html). Though personally I find the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37892831/104223) [approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37929844/104223) much more readable - technically it *could* be done with a regular expression.

For example, you could create an expression which matches the entire line and use multiple subexpressions to match the desired number of characters in each field. Then use the generated backreferences to create your pipe delimited string, ie `\1|\2|\3 ....`

**Code:** *Tested with CF11*

```
// ^ - starting with
// $ - ending with
// ( ) - subexpression or capturing group
// \1 - backreference, 1 corresponds to first subexpression
result = REReplace(line1
           ,"^(.{7})(.{10})(.{47})(.{34})(.{14})(.{13})(.{15})(.{22})(.{28})(.{18})(.{2})\s+$"
           , "\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7|\8|\9|\10|\11"
        );
```

**Sample data:**

```
A1     B         C                                              D                                 E             F            G              H                     I                           J                 K   
A2     B         C                                              D                                 E             F            G              H                     I                           J                 K   
A3     B         C                                              D                                 E             F            G              H                     I                           J                 K
```

If you dump the results, and check the `len()` of each field, you will see the spaces *are* preserved. So the problem is the original expression.

```
for (currValue in listToArray(line1, "|")) {
    writeOutput("<br>["& len(currValue) &"] "& currValue );
}
```

**Results:**

```
[7 ] A1     |
[10] B         |
[47] C                                              |
[34] D                                 |
[14] E             |
[13] F            |
[15] G              |
[22] H                     |
[28] I                           |
[18] J                 |
[2 ] K |
```

Comment: Never used this with a regular expression, cool functionality though. I get it now with the whitespace and writeDump(). Also, i ended up skipping the query construction and used just the arrays to put the data into a struct. which is serialized to json and passed on to another department for data entry. what would be your suggestion on database entry

Comment: Depends on your set up. If the file just needs to be inserted into a database that is accessible to CF, it is usually simpler to use your db's loading tools. For example, `BULK INSERT` in sql server, `LOAD DATA` in mySQL, etctera.